# How to take datetime.time type input through django forms and performing arithmetic operations on it in django models?

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, django-views

my models.py:

```
class Attendancename(models.Model):
    teacher_name = models.ForeignKey(Teachername)
    date = models.DateField('Date')
    intime = models.TimeField('IN-TIME')
    outtime = models.TimeField('OUT-TIME')

    def hours_conversion(self):
        tdelta = (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(),outtime) - datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(),intime))

        return (tdelta).second/3600

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" %self.teacher_name
```

my views.py:

```
def add_atten(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AttendancenameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('student:listatten'))
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:       
         form = AttendancenameForm()
    return render(request, 'add_atten.html', {'form': form},)
```

my forms.py:

```
class AttendancenameForm(ModelForm):
        teacher_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Teachername.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Attendancename
        fields = ('teacher_name', 'date', 'intime', 'outtime',)
```

I want to calculate time difference from `'intime'` and `'outtime'` attributes. But I got unexpected error: `'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time''`.Please help me to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in django, but seems like `intime` and `outtime` are of type `datetime.time` , you cannot use the `-` operator to subtract them, instead try using the following -

```
import datetime
outtime = datetime.time(10,0)
intime = datetime.time(5,0)
tdelta = (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(),outtime) - datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(),intime))
print(tdelta.seconds/3600)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. How can I make it to interpret difference of time as `'am'` and `'pm'`?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by interpret difference of time as 'am' 'pm' ? datetime.time() does not store that info , its a 24 hour clock

Comment: If you are talking about interpreting it from strings, then you can use the format `%p` for 'AM' or 'PM' , you would also need to format the hour by using `%I` at that time.

Comment: when I'm submitting outtime in my form it takes time after 12:00 noon as 'pm'. when I'm submiting out time value - `'06:00'` in my form then it shows it as 'am' time and time diffrence value shown by it is - '21 hours', inspite of 9 hrs as my intime is `'9:00'`am. So Is there any way to do so?

Comment: The issue maybe where you are converting the time from inputs in your site to the model.

Comment: I'm sorry this is exact issue -  when I'm submitting outtime in my form it takes time after 12:00 noon as 'am'.  I'm submiting out time value - `'06:00'` in my form then it shows it as 'am' time and time diffrence value shown by it is - '21 hours', inspite of 9 hrs as my intime is `'9:00'`am. So Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Like I said the issue maybe with the place where you convert the inputted strings to datetime. show us that code

Comment: Try setting `TIME_INPUT_FORMATS` with `%p` . Documentation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_INPUT_FORMATS
Check it out

Comment: As per your suggestion I've updated my models.py file but I think I've not done such kind of conversion...

Comment: Check the documentation i provided